# reformatting table with various copy paste

Tags: text-formatting

I have something like this in a file:

```
00550 Peptidoglycan biosynthesis (2)
K01000
K02563
00511 Other glycan degradation (6)
K01190
K01191
K01192
K01201
K01227
K12309
```

I need something like this :

```
K01000,00550,Peptidoglycan biosynthesis (2)
K02563,00550,Peptidoglycan biosynthesis (2)
K01190,00511, Other glycan degradation (6)
K01191,00511, Other glycan degradation (6)
K01192,00511, Other glycan degradation (6)
K01201,00511, Other glycan degradation (6)
K01227,00511, Other glycan degradation (6)
K12309,00511, Other glycan degradation (6)
```

How I can do that in linux?

Comment: `awk 'NF>1{sub(" ",",");t=$0;next}{print $0","t}' your_file`

Comment: Thanks, this command works perfectly , if this was not to much work for you I would ask you to give me explain me the different fragment of the code. This would help me to edit it when my dataset is coming differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
awk -vOFS=, '/^[0-9]* / {$1 = $1; GL = $0; next} {print $0, GL}' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works but without  the -v option, and id doest not put the comma. it looks that awk doesn't have this -v option.

Comment: That surprised me much ... try `OFS=","`

Comment: It is still not woking and giving the same result with out the comma,  but I really love  the simplicity of this code,    I start understanding what it is doing, I think it is really power full. Thanks

Comment: I would be very happy if you could make  a glance on it again and try to fix  tu put the coma as mentioned in the post,  this will be very helpful

Comment: I'd be glad to help if I only knew how. It's tested and known to work. More details needed (e.g. how it failed). `OFS` is the output field separator, which you can set with the `-v` option, anywhere in the script, esp. in the `BEGIN´ section, or after the script as a variable assignment `OFS=","`.

Comment: Thanks  for your help, finally the output was ok since it could be reformatted in  excel. Thanks again

Comment: Formatting in EXCEL should be considered LAST resort and very unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/(/{s/ /,/;h;d;};G;s/\n/,/' filename
```

The `sed` expression, one instruction at a time:

```
/(/{
#use "(" to spot a new name
    s/ /,/  #replace first space (after the number) with ,
    h       #save it in the hold space
    d       #delete (don't output) and start next cycle (read next line)
}
#only reached when no "(" found
G           #append saved text from hold to current line
s/\n/,/     #replace the linebreak with a ,
```

Comment: Thanks , it works with the new suggestion by putting ; after d